# how to create following divs?

Tags: html, css

Sorry but having difficulty in creating a group of div as attached pic..please help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ClxP.jpg

my biggest problem is having to get the divs arranged next to each other inside of parent divs. Infact to go to a next level, if there is a 5th div of 200px then I want it to automatically come to the second line. 
I understand I need something to do with CSS, just that am not so well versed with it.

```
.div_main_left {
    width: 800px;
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 600px;
        float: left;
        display: table-cell;
}

.div_sec_left {
    width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 75px;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
}

.div_right {
    width: 250px;
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 500px;
        float: right;
        display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you upload what you have to a [jsfiddle?](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

HTML

```
<div id="mainwrapper">
 <div id="leftwrapper">
     <div class="topbox"></div>
     <div class="topbox"></div>
     <div class="topbox"></div>
     <div class="topbox"></div>
     <div id="maincontent"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="rightwrapper">
     <div id="topsidebar"></div>
     <div id="bottomsidebar"></div>
 </div>     
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mainwrapper{
 width:1050px;    
}

#rightwrapper{
 width:250px;
 float:left;
}

#leftwrapper{
 width:800px;
 float:left;
}

.topbox{
 float: left;
 width:196px;
 margin-right:4px;
 height:75px;
 background-color:orange;    
}

#maincontent{
 width:100%;
 height:675px;
 background-color:blue;
 clear:both;    
}

#topsidebar
{
 width:100%;
 height:600px;
 background-color:green;    
}

#bottomsidebar{
 width:100%;
 height:150px;    
 background-color:red;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vEXrw/4/) is the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a list then style the list itself. From: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

```
#tabs ul {
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
display: inline;
} 

#tabs ul li {
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 2px 15px 5px;
border: 1px solid #000;
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}


#tabs ul li.here {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc;
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:
[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vEXrw/3/)

First the html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="big_left">
        <div class="float_parent">
            <div class="small">200x75</div>
            <div class="small">200x75</div>
            <div class="small">200x75</div>
            <div class="small">200x75</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            The Content;
        </div>
    </div><!-- Big left End -->

    <div class="big_right">
        <div class="right_long">
            250x750
        </div>      
    </div><!-- Big Right End -->
</div>
```

Then the css:

```
#container {
    width:1065px;
}
.big_left {
    width:810px;
    float:left;
}
.big_right {
    width:255px;
    float:left;
}
.big_left .float_parent {
    width:800px;
}
.big_left .float_parent .small{
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
}
.big_left .content {
    clear:both;
}
.big_right .right_long {
    width:250px;
    height:750px;
}
```